# How to create dummy values and replace the original data in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have a data like above. I want to write a vba code to do a if logic test on the cells from B2 to J11.

IF any of B2 to J11 >0 positive, then the original value would become 1,
otherwise it become 0.

If you can do it simply in excel, also let me know. I tried the IF function, it can only work for one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a formula that changes a cell in-place.  That would require VBA.

This is my first VBA post, so I'm open to any pointers from the experts:

```
Sub Replace()
  For Each c In Selection
    If c.Value > 0 Then
      c.Value = 1
    ElseIf c.Value < 0 Then
      c.Value = 0
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

You can also change to 0 and 1 using search/replace.

Highlight the data, then:

- Search/replace `-*` for `0`.
- Search/replace `*.*` for `1`.

Comment: Since you only have 2 possibilities with the code you can simply use `Else` with no condition.  Also, searching for `*.*` would also include negative values since `*` also matches `-`.  Other than that: fantastically elegant.

Comment: Thanks, @jbarker2160!  I considered excluding `ElseIf`, but that would change blank cells to 0.  (Maybe there's a way around that?)  Also, if the search/replaces are done in order, there would be no negative numbers when doing the search/replace for `*.*`.